# Porting preg_match_all go js regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex, node.js

I'm trying to port a PHP script to Nodejs, I did most of the work, but I couldn't solve this:
I got:

```
preg_match_all("@(==[^=]+==)(.+?(?=[^=]==[^=]|$))@s", $this->source, $paragraphs);
```

How will the JS version look like?
I've tried with the following:

```
this.content.match(/(==[^=]+==)(.+?(?=[^=]==[^=]|$))/ig);
```

but the result is messy.

If I add `s` flag I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'igs'
at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
at WikiParser.makeContent (D:\Smartly\application\models\parser.js:14:2)
at D:\Smartly\application\models\parser.js:63:10
at Request._callback (D:\Smartly\application\models\webworker.js:21:3)
at Request.self.callback (D:\Smartly\node_modules\request\request.js:129:22)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Smartly\node_modules\request\request.js:873:14)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\Smartly\node_modules\request\request.js:824:12)
 at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

Comment: The only difference is that you forgot to use the `s` modifier. So use `/igs` instead of `/ig`

Comment: Edited it. [too short]

Comment: @HamZa: the s modifier doesn't exist in javascript. The "classic way" is to replace the dot with `[\s\S]` to avoid the problem, but here it seems to be better to replace `.+?` by `[\s\S][^=]*`. As an aside comment: the `i` modifier is useless here.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte facepalm. Thanks for the reminder !

Comment: @HamZa: I think you are only tired. <°)))))>